# Missing template error when using Ajax to load data on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, templates, routes

I'm trying to load the saved data using AJAX, to avoid refreshing the whole web page. I've been watching the [rails cast Jquery Ajax video episode 136](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery).

The problem occurs when I save the data on the rendered form. When I click save button nothing happens, but making a debug on chrome developer tool, I found the error `ActionView::MissingTemplate in Locations#create`. Locations is my model, and create the action to create.

I've Spent a lot of hours trying to find out what's wrong, and watching again and again the rail casts without any result. Please if someone could help.

**This is the controller file locations_controller.rb**

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @locations = Location.all
    @json = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails 
  end 

  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  def edit
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.js   
    end
  end

def show
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @location }
    end
  end
  def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.update_attributes(params[:location])
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @location.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to locations_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

**This is the model file location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :gmaps, :latitude, :longitude, :name
  validates_presence_of :name, :address

  acts_as_gmappable :check_process => false


  def gmaps4rails_address
    address
  end

   def gmaps4rails_infowindow  
  "<h1>#{self.name}</h1>"
  end

  def gmaps4rails_sidebar
   "<h4>#{name}</h4>" 
  end
end
```

**The new.js.erb file**

```
$('#new_link').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

**The create.js.erb file**

```
$('#new_location').remove();
$('#new_link').show();
$('#allsites').empty().append('<%= j render(@location) %>');
```

**The index.html.erb**

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json}) %>  


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= location.name %></td>
    <td><%= location.address %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', location %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_path(location) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', location, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<div id="allsites">
//here I want to load all the data, ignore the table above
  </div>


<%= link_to 'New Location', new_location_path, id:"new_link", remote: true%>

<br />
```

Also the `:remote => true` has been added to the form

**Partial _form.html.erb file**

```
<%= form_for(@location, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <% if @location.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@location.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this location from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @location.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :latitude %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :longitude %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :gmaps %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :gmaps %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Working on Rails 3.2.13
This is my source http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

Any help or sugestion will be apretiated, have a nice day everybody

EDIT: I'm sorry I forgot the screenshots 
[image: HTML error 500 Crhome debug tool]

[image: Missing Template error]

Comment: What exactly is your error?

Comment: Yeah, please attach a screenshot or paste a full backtrace of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `create` action, you are not saving the object.  All you are doing is making a call to `new`.  You probably want to save it using `@location.save` after the call to `new` or use the `create` method instead:

```
@location = Location.create(params[:location])
```

Then your `redirect_to @location` goes to your `show` action which also needs a `show.html.erb` which you do not seem to have and that is probably the reason why you are getting the `MissingTemplate` error.

Oh, saw your screenshot, you don't have location partial defined as shown in your second screenshot. Since you're passing `@location` it's looking for `_location.html.erb` Please add that partial and use location to use your location's attributes instead of `@location`. Please report back if it still gives you problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, this project was created using the scaffold generator all the realted files and views were created and used to work correctly. And yes I have the show.html.erb file too. Maybe the create.js.erb could be wrong?

Comment: Did you change the line `@location = Location.new(params[:location])` to `@location = Location.create(params[:location])`? Since you are not actually saving it, the renderer is not able to find it.  Please change that line and give it a try.

Comment: Yes I did, but still get the same error message "missing template...." did I tipe wrong this line? `$('#allsites').empty().append('<%= j render(@location) %>');`

Comment: Oh, saw your screenshot, you don't have `location` partial defined as shown in your second screenshot.  Since you're passing `@location` it's looking for `_location.html.erb`.  Please add that partial and use `location` to use your `location`'s attributes instead of `@location`.  Please report back if it still gives you problem.

Comment: Fixed ,Thanks for your Help, once I created the _location.html.erb , the new record refreshed immediately, now I have to figure it out how to display all the other records in the same view like a list. Maybe in another POST thanks.

Comment: Great, I guess the reason you didn't notice the extra partial in your tutorial is because the tutorial already had `_task.html.erb`.